# Proof that the middle line of a trapezoid bisects any segment that joins points from its bases

Tags: euclidean-geometry

I know that the *middle line* of a trapezoid is the line that joins the midpoints of the non-parallel sides, and that it is parallel to the bases of the trapezoid.

> How do I prove that the middle line of a trapezoid bisects any segment that joins points from its bases?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Consider using the [intercept theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intercept_theorem).
[image]

This theorem tells us the following: Since $DG\parallel EI\parallel AH$:

> $$\frac{GI}{IH}=\frac{DE}{EA}=1$$